# socket.io app fails when many clients are connected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I coded a feature for one of my sites that would push an alert to a user when another user sends them a message. The feature works in development and in production if I only enable it for a few users. The feature then fails miserably (the push alert stops being sent) when enabled for a few thousand concurrent users (the server stays up so it's not simply dying). From the logs it seems that the socket isn't being found in the 'send_msg' event.

I also noticed that when I try to access http://www.mydomain.com:4086/socket.io/socket.io.js directly from the browser, sometimes it loads and sometimes it doesn't and I have no idea what the cause may be. Does anything look wrong in the code I posted below? I've been bashing my head over this for the last three days.

**Edit:** It looks like raising the ulimit from 1024 to 65535 buys the application a few more minutes before it starts failing with "warn  - client not handshaken client should reconnect" and "warn  - websocket parser error: no handler for opcode 10" errors again. I'm sure I don't have anywhere near 65535 concurrent connections at one time. Can someone explain if I'm on the right track?

**Server code (server.js):**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(4086);
var clients = {};

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('login', function (data) {
        if (typeof data.id_user !== 'undefined' && data.id_user > 0) {
            socket.set('id_user', data.id_user, function() {});
            clients[data.id_user] = socket.id;
        }
    });

    socket.on('send_msg', function (data) {
        if (typeof io.sockets.sockets[clients[data.id_sendee]] !== 'undefined') {
            var sendeeSocket = io.sockets.sockets[clients[data.id_sendee]];
            sendeeSocket.emit('newalert', {
                sender_profile: data.sender_profile,
                msg: data.msg,
                send_to: data.send_to });
        }
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        socket.get('id_user', function (err, id_user) {
            if (typeof id_user !== 'undefined' && id_user > 0) {
                delete clients[id_user];
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Client code:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com:4086/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://www.mydomain.com:4086');

    socket.emit('login', { id_user: <?=$idUser?> });

    socket.on('newalert', function (data) {
        $("#msg_stream").hide();
        $("#stream_sender_profile").html(data.sender_profile);
        $("#stream_msg").text(data.msg);
        $("#stream_send_to").html(data.send_to);
        $("#msg_stream").fadeIn();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

.......

<script>
    // Alert stream
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit_btn").click(function() {
            var msg = $("#message").val();
            if (msg) {
                if (msg.length > 255) {
                    msg = msg.substr(0, 255) + '...';
                }
                socket.emit('send_msg', {
                    sender_profile: '<a href="/profile/view/<?=$idUser?>" class="stream_dismiss"><?=$username?></a>',
                    id_sendee: <?=$idSendee?>,
                    msg: msg,
                    send_to: '<?=isset($streamSendTo) ? $streamSendTo : '';?>' });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is failing?

Comment: The push alert stops being sent when a large number of users connect. From the logs, it seems that the socket isn't being found when the message is sent.

Comment: so did you resolve your issue? 'cos i have the same and i can not find and answers

Comment: Hi Dmitriy. Yes, I did eventually manage to resolve this and properly configure my application. I'll update this post with an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to resolve my connection issues and my solution mostly revolves around optimal server configuration.

**Node.js code (index.js)**

```js
var arguments = process.argv.slice(2);
if( ! arguments[0]) {
    console.log("Error: Missing port.");
    process.exit(1);
}
var serverPort = arguments[0];
var redisHost = '127.0.0.1';
var redisPort = 6379;

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: redisHost, port: redisPort }));

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log(socket.id + ' user connected!');

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log(socket.id + ' user disconnected');
  });
});

http.listen(serverPort, function(){
  console.log('listening on localhost:' + serverPort);
});
```

Unlike the code I posted in the question, I no longer submit the messages to node.js but instead through my web application which interfaces with socket.io directly. This decision was unrelated to performance so feel free to build the script out further.

**Configure your server**

*Increase open files limit (Include whichever user you specify for your node processes)* (/etc/security/limits.conf):

```
*                soft    nofile          999999
*                hard    nofile          999999
root             soft    nofile          999999
root             hard    nofile          999999
```

*Tune server networking:*

*See: https://engineering.gosquared.com/optimising-nginx-node-js-and-networking-for-heavy-workloads*

/etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range='1024 65000'
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse='1'
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout='15'
net.core.netdev_max_backlog='4096'
net.core.rmem_max='16777216'
net.core.somaxconn='4096'
net.core.wmem_max='16777216'
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog='20480'
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets='400000'
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save='1'
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem='4096 87380 16777216'
net.ipv4.tcp_syn_retries='2'
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries='2'
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem='4096 65536 16777216'
vm.min_free_kbytes='65536'
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (for clustering and sticky sessions):

```
http {
    ...
    upstream io_nodes {
       # Enabled sticky sessions
       ip_hash;
       server 127.0.0.1:3000;
       server 127.0.0.1:3001;
       server 127.0.0.1:3002;
       server 127.0.0.1:3003;
    }

    server {
        ...

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host \$host;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_pass http://io_nodes;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I tried to use the cluster module for node but I couldn't get it to properly pass messages between users on different cluster nodes for whatever reason despite using Redis as a shared medium so I manually configured clustering and sticky sessions in Nginx. Then I run index.js with the ports I specified in nginx.conf:

```
node index.js 3000
node index.js 3001
node index.js 3002
node index.js 3003
```